# 64-bit specific simd intrinsic

Tags: c, sse, simd, sse2

I am using the following union declaration in SSE2.

```
typedef unsigned long uli;  
typedef uli v4si __attribute__ ((vector_size(16)));  
typedef union  
{  
    v4si v;  
    uli data[2];  
} uliv;  

uliv a, b, c;
```

The idea is assign two unsigned long variables (64 bit long) to each a and b, XOR them and place the result in c.

An explicit assignment (`a.data[0] = something`) works here but it requires more time.

I plan to use intrinsics. If I use `_mm_set_epi64 (unsigned long x, unsigned long y)`, it asks for `__m64` variables. If I cast these variables `(__m64)x` and it works fine, but it gives wrong result.

```
for (k = 0; k < 10; k++)  
{  
    simda.v = _mm_set_epi64 (_mulpre1[u1][k], _mulpre2[u2][k]);  
    simdb.v = _mm_set_epi64 (res1[i+k], res2[i+k]);  
    simdc.v = _mm_xor_si128 (simda.v, simdb.v);  
}
```

The above code gives error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/include/emmintrin.h:578: note: expected ‘__m64’
but argument is of type ‘long unsigned int’
```

Can you please suggest some alternatives (intrinsics)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you *sure* that `unsigned long` is 64 bits on your system ? It's probably safer to use `unsigned long long` or better yet `uint64_t` from `<stdint.h>`.

On my system `_mm_set_epi64` takes two `unsigned long long` parameters and returns an `__m128i`.

It's not clear from your question whether you just want to (a) XOR two 64 bit values or (b) XOR two vectors of 2 x 64 bit values ?

For case (a) just use scalar code, e.g.

```
uint64_t a, b, c;

c = a ^ b;
```

For case (b) you don't need unions etc, just do this:

```
__m128i va, vb, vc;

va = _mm_set_epi64(a1, a2);
vb = _mm_set_epi64(b1, b2);
vc = _mm_xor_si128(va, vb);
```

Comment: 1. unsigned long is 64 bits in my machine. case (b) will be applicable for my program. a1, a2 are unsigned long elements, but I get the following error (without casting by __m64)                                          : /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/include/emmintrin.h:578: note: expected ‘__m64’ but argument is of type ‘long unsigned int’

Comment: @anup: is this part of a loop, i.e. do you have arrays of values that you need to XOR. If so then there's probably a better overall solution to this.

Comment: yeah, it is a part of a loop...what is the better solution? The situation is like this, for each iteration I take two values from two different arrays (not necessarily same index), and another two values from two different arrays, XOR them and place them into second set of arrays..

Comment: @anup: also note that with newer versions of gcc and emmintrin.h you might need to use `_mm_set_epi64x` rather than `_mm_set_epi64`. From gcc 4.3 onwards you may also need `gcc -flax-vector-conversions` to get older SSE code to compile.

Comment: @anup: you should probably load vectors from your 4 source arrays, shuffle the values into appropriate temporary vectors, then do the XORs. The idea is to do *everything* inside the loop with SSE, not mix scalar and SIMD code.

Comment: using gcc 4.4.3 and compiling with -flax-vector-conversions, with _mm_set_epi64x, it compiled but generated wrong results..

Comment: @anup: "generated wrong results" doesn't help much - you'll need to either post your code or do some debugging

Comment: please see the above question edit..by generated wrong results I mean when I do explicit assignment (like simda.data[0] = .., and simda.data[1] = ..) it matches with correct result but when I replace it with _mm_set_epi64 as stated earlier it gives error, when replaced with _mm_set_epi64x it compiles and the result does not match

Comment: Thanx, it worked, actually I made a mistake when using _mm_set_epi64x with ordering of data...Now it works fine, though it takes considerable amount of time.

Comment: @anup: you're probably generating a lot of scalar instructions and memory accesses behind the scenes when using _mm_set_epi64, so your SIMD instructions will be of little benefit. Post the code as a new question, perhaps, and then we can see if we can optimise it properly.